# Saving pandas data frame to .mat file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame 'df', it looks like below but original data has many rows.

[image]

I would like to save this as .mat file with a name 'meta.mat'. I tried;

```
import scipy.io as sio
sio.savemat(os.path.join(destination_folder_path,'meta.mat'), df)
```

This creates the meta.mat file but it only writes the field names, when I open it in matlab it looks like this;

[image]

How can I fix this, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a `pd.DataFrame` directly when `scipy.io.savemat` is expecting a dict of `numpy` arrays. Try replacing `df` with the following in your call to savemat:

```
 {name: col.values for name, col in df.items()}
```

Comment: Error 
  File "c:/lib/site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 665, in write
    self.write_cells(narr)
  File "c:/lib/site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 770, in write_cells
    self.write(el)
  File "c:/lib/site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 655, in write
    % (arr, type(arr)))
TypeError: Could not convert None (type <class 'NoneType'>) to array

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution. The resulting mat file will in the form of a structure in *matlab*

```py
# data dictionary
OutData = {} 

# convert DF to dictionary before loading to your dictionary
OutData['Obj'] = df.to_dict('list')

sio.savemat('path\\testmat.mat',OutData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, to make it more useful could you share the related documentation and a working example. Then, could you make things more explicits like writing keyword parameters properly (df.to_df(orient='list')).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).